# i uploaded a custom theme on wordpress but its style is not working i cannot enqueue the style

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, wordpress

i uploaded a custom theme on wordpress as a parent theme but the problem is only simple text is showing on the screen no style is working no image or slider is working except blue text. As i am new in php i do not know how to enqueue the style in functions.php.

Here is my functions.php:

```
<?php 

wp_enqueue_style( 'flattern-style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); //default

wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘/custom.css' ); //our stylesheet

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flattern_scripts_styles' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` must inside of `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook callback function check code below.

```
<?php 

function flattern_scripts_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style('flattern-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', array(), time(), false);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘/custom.css' ); //our stylesheet
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flattern_scripts_styles' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but still its not working

Comment: here is the code      <?php 

function flattern_scripts_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flattern-style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); //default
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style’, get_template_directory_uri() . ‘/assets/css/style.css' ); //our stylesheet
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'flattern_scripts_styles' );

?>

Comment: in which path `flattern-style` you out?

Comment: this path /assets/css/style.css

Comment: child theme or main theme?

Comment: thank you now style is applied but one thing more i want to ask only simple css starts working but i had used jsons sliders etc they are not working how to enqueue them in functions.php from the header

Comment: <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: You can use same `wp_enqueue_style`. duplicate and use as per your need.